# Как склеить текст (стилизованный css) и картинку средствами JS (пример в приложении)

Tags: javascript, svg, png, gif, jpeg

Задача такая, на сайте хочу добавить возможность менять картинку, точнее добавлять текст для гравировки на кольцо, для этого необходимо чтобы создавалась картинка с превью в виде png,svg,jpg. Текст вводит клиент, выбирает шрифт, а уже с применением css и эффектов это c прозрачным фоном добавляется на существующее кольцо (становится одной картинкой) и ее уже можно отправлять мне как образец для работы над продуктом... как такое можно сделать?

[image: Кольцо с текстом css на JS]

Answer (score 3):

```js
document.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  document.querySelector('textPath').textContent = e.target.value;
})
```

```css
path { fill: none; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1px; }
text { font-size: 15px; }
```

```html
<input autofocus><br>

<svg width="300" height="225">
  <image xlink:href="//i.stack.imgur.com/54Sq9.jpg" />
  <defs>
    <path id="path-for-text" d="M133,129 C139,145 186,173 238,157" />
  </defs>
  <text>
    <textPath xlink:href="#path-for-text">Ash nazg durbatulûk</textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Хочу печатку с таким шрифтом!

Comment: "становится одной картинкой" - вы не много не поняли... пример в прикрепленном файле - готовый вид картинки... то есть jpg вместе с текстом стал одним файлом.

Comment: @MaxKievSky, в чём проблема? Тогда грузите картинку и клейте, например, через PHP: http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.image.php

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, даже пример нашел jQuery Ui + PHP GD - 
https://github.com/Ipatov/jqury_ui_and_php_gd

Comment: @MaxKievSky, вообще-то svg - это и есть одна картинка.

Comment: Имелось ввиду именно склеенная картинка тескт + картинка(jpg) = jpg. Извиняюсь, если не правильно четко поставил задачу.